# Haskell Yesod on Windows 7: Launching development server with 'yesod devel' issue

Tags: haskell, yesod

I am very new to Haskell and I am currently using Windows 7 OS.

I am attempting to develop a web service using Haskell framework Yesod. When I execute the `yesod devel` command to start the development server, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Sticky\workspace\Yesod\testYesod>yesod devel 
Yesod devel server. Press ENTER to quit
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring testYesod-0.0.0...
cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing:
data-default -any,
hamlet ==1.1.*,
hjsmin ==0.1.*,
http-conduit >=1.5 && <1.7,
monad-control ==0.3.*,
persistent ==1.0.*,
persistent-sqlite ==1.0.*,
shakespeare-css ==1.0.*,
shakespeare-js ==1.0.*,
shakespeare-text ==1.0.*,
wai-extra ==1.3.*,
warp ==1.3.*,
yaml ==0.8.*,
yesod ==1.1.*,
yesod-auth ==1.1.*,
yesod-core >=1.1.2 && <1.2,
yesod-default ==1.1.*,
yesod-form ==1.1.*,
yesod-static ==1.1.*,
yesod-test ==0.3.*
Rebuilding application...
Forcing recompile for .\Model.hs because of config/models
Forcing recompile for .\Foundation.hs because of config/routes
Forcing recompile for .\Foundation.hs because of messages/en.msg
Forcing recompile for .\Foundation.hs because of templates/default-layout-wrappe
r.hamlet
Forcing recompile for .\Foundation.hs because of templates/default-layout.hamlet

Forcing recompile for .\Handler\Home.hs because of templates/homepage.hamlet
cabal: Run the 'configure' command fBuild failure, pausing...
irst.
```

I have tried to run `cabal configure` and this seems to execute fine though I feel I am missing something due to my inexperience, any direction would be much appreciated. I have not been able to find any related questions but again this is likely due to my not knowing exactly what I need to know :)

Comment: Try `cabal install --only-dependencies` in your project directory.  edit:  Oh, and run `cabal install happy alex` before you do that.  `hjsmin` requires at least `alex`, not sure about happy but it can't hurt.  Then make sure they're on your path before running the first command.

Comment: Cheers! Worked like a charm :D

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the dependencies for your project aren't installed.  Run the following commands in your project directory:

```
# alex at least, possibly also happy, are required by hjsmin
cabal install happy alex 
# Make sure alex is on your path, then
cabal install --only-dependencies
```